# Splitting a string in java with respect to a word

Tags: java

How do I separate a String say "The Lazy dog is running fast" with respect to "dog" so that I get Strings ="The Lazy", "dog","is running fast"? in Java

the code I am using 
        String str="The lazy dog is running like a dog";
        String dog="dog";
        String[] strArr= str.split(dog);
        for(int i=0;i

It returns:
The lazy 
 is running like a

Comment: well I am for now doing it using split(" "). but that just splits every word.

Comment: How should it choose the word that we split before and after it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (and grouping). Regular expressions can be used to match pretty much whatever you want!

e.g.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class PatternExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String split = "The Lazy dog is running fast";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(dog)(.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(split);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++){
                System.out.println(i + "->" + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
0->The Lazy dog is running fast
1->The Lazy 
2->dog
3-> is running fast
```

**Take 2: No regex**

```
public class PatternExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String split = "The Lazy dog is running fast";
        String word = "dog";
        String tmp = split;
        while (tmp.contains(word)){
            int x = tmp.indexOf(word);
            System.out.println(tmp.substring(0,x));
            System.out.println(word);
            tmp = tmp.substring(x+word.length());
        }
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just had to mention: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: IMO, using regular expression is an overkill here in this case. As he just needed to search the exact "word" not a "pattern".

Comment: I think that is just what I need. I might just have to modify the regex a bit, I will give it a try

Comment: Haha, a good read. It lead me to this -> http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247 . Overkill it may be, but there are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Damn I am not allowed to use that import. ! :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly, if so, here is how I would start about it, you still need to fill the gaps for edge cases. You can use `substring` and `indexOf` instead of `split`, but it seems too convenient not to use it.

```
package test;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "The Lazy dog is running fast";
        String word = "dog";
        String[] splitByWord = splitByWord(word, sentence);
        for (String string : splitByWord) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    }

    public static String[] splitByWord(String word, String sentence) {
        String[] split = sentence.split(" " + word + " ");
        //TODO: handle edge cases where word is not found in sentence, or first word, or last
        return new String[]{split[0], word, split[1]};
    }
}
```

Comment: this works fine if the dog is in center or somewhere, how about for this "Dog is very lazy today"-> "Dog","is very lazy today".. the problem is I don't know where in the string will be splitting word will appear